# Reading items with LIKE in a function that splits

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a query that uses a function called "My_Splitter" when I pass a string like

"this is an example", it returns

```
this
is
an
example
```

The problem I am having in my query is that I need to take each of those values and do something like

```
select value from My_Splitter(@MyString) where value LIKE '%this%' or value LIKE '%is%' or value LIKE '%an%' or value like '%example%'
```

you get my idea...  here is my query

```
 select                 
  DISTINCT(pr.myID)            
 from                 
  myProducts pr               
  left JOIN pcategory pc ON pr.ProductId = pc.ProductId                
  left JOIN category ca on ca.categoryid = pc.categoryid       
  left join sNumber zs on zs.productid=pr.productid                
 where                 
  pr.activated = 1               
  and pr.PortalId = @PortalId                
  and (pr.Name like '%' + @Keyword + '%'  
  or pr.Name in (select value from SC_Splitter(@Keyword,' ')) //PROBLEM HERE

  or pr.myTitle LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' 

  or pr.PRnum LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'       
  or zs.snum like   '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

I WISH I COULD JUST DO

`or pr.Name LIKE (select value from SC_Splitter(@Keyword,' '))`  and it would take any value from @Keywprd and so a LIKE search on each :( lol

Comment: Please tag your question with the brand of RDBMS you use.  SQL is a language, not a technology product.  I guess you are using Microsoft SQL Server, since you use `+` for string concatenation.  Add tags `sql-server` or `sql-server-2008`, etc.

Comment: CORRECTION, THE KEYWORD CONTAINS DIFFERENT "NAMES" I WOULD LIKE TO FIND ALL THE ID'S WHERE THOSE NAMES EXIST...

Comment: i am doing a search on the key words, so basically if I do "ties with buttons" it returns 3 items which is ok.. but if I do "ties buttons" it only returns one.,,

Comment: similarly if I do "ties with" it works... but "with ties" wont

Comment: Totally off-topic but I'd love to see an option to click on a comment and convert it to lower or proper case. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use CROSS APPLY.

```
 select
  DISTINCT(pr.myID)
 from
  myProducts pr
  left JOIN pcategory pc ON pr.ProductId = pc.ProductId
  left JOIN category ca on ca.categoryid = pc.categoryid
  left join sNumber zs on zs.productid=pr.productid

  CROSS APPLY SC_Splitter(@keyword,' ') AS sentance

 where                 
  pr.activated = 1               
  and pr.PortalId = @PortalId                

  and (pr.Name like '%' + @Keyword + '%'  
      OR pr.name LIKE '%' + Sentance.Value + '%')

  or pr.myTitle LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'     
  or pr.PRnum LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'       
  or zs.snum like   '%' + @Keyword + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) in Microsoft SQL Server, the difficulty goes away, and your searches will be orders of magnitude faster.

```
select                 
  DISTINCT(pr.myID)            
 from                 
  myProducts pr               
  left JOIN pcategory pc ON pr.ProductId = pc.ProductId                
  left JOIN category ca on ca.categoryid = pc.categoryid       
  left join sNumber zs on zs.productid=pr.productid                
 where                 
  pr.activated = 1               
  and pr.PortalId = @PortalId                
  and (CONTAINS(pr.Name, @Keyword)  
  or FREETEXT(pr.Name, @Keyword) //NO PROBLEM HERE
  ...
```

Comment: This is so clean, but it tells me that table can not use CONTAINS or FREETEXT because it is not FULL TEXT indexed and I cant make changes to those tables :(

Comment: Correct, if you read the documentation I linked to, full-text search requires creation of a special type of index.  If you can't create that index, then you can't use these search functions.  But for what it's worth, that's the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: Questions, as new records come in or created is there anything I have to do? or once the index is created I am good to go?

Comment: Yes, the index incorporates new data automatically.

Comment: Great I am going to look into this to improve this later.. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i suggest restructuring your splitter to a new function that can accept two strings, the name and the 'sentence'

then that function would loop over the parsed sentence to see if it matches the name and return a 1 if found, and a 0 if not.

then your query would simply have a `where my_new_function( name, sentence ) = 1` line

Answer (score 1):

This fixes the issue with your solution., but Bill Karwin's answer is the *correct* solution for the problem.

To save time and more questions, this can't be optimised. The main reason is leading wildcards. Use Full Text Search if you want "fast" as well as "working"

Basically, JOIN using LIKE

```
 select                 
  DISTINCT(pr.myID)            
 from                 
  myProducts pr               
  left JOIN pcategory pc ON pr.ProductId = pc.ProductId                
  left JOIN category ca on ca.categoryid = pc.categoryid       
  left join sNumber zs on zs.productid=pr.productid  

  JOIN 
  SC_Splitter(@Keyword,' ') CSV ON pr.Name LIKE '%' + CSV.value + '%'

 where                 
  pr.activated = 1               
  and pr.PortalId = @PortalId                
  and

--fix your parenthesis after this. 
--I'm not sure what was intended above

 (pr.Name like '%' + @Keyword + '%'  

  or pr.myTitle LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%' 

  or pr.PRnum LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'       
  or zs.snum like   '%' + @Keyword + '%' 
 )
```